# window.location.assign отрабатывает лишь 1 раз, а должен 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

"Next" пишет 3 раза, а window.location.assign отрабатывает лишь раз (скачивается сгенерированный файл в ответе от сервера). Почему?

```
$.get("", { name: name, img: img, price: price, url: url })
      .done(function(data) {
        window.location.assign("/slave/instagram/parse/?name=" +name + "&img=" + img + "&price=" + price + "&url=" + url + "&category_id=" + category_id);
        console.log("Next");
      });
```

Comment: почему 3 раза?.

Comment: А там все в цикле, и нужно получать каждый раз новый файл в зависимости от входных данных.

Comment: Мне кажется или после первого выполнения `assign`, страница должна обновится до указанного url, т.е. после обновления она потеряет свое действие и после ее вызова, опять произойдет смена на первый url. И так по кругу. Конечно, я могу ошибаться.

Comment: Если у вас эти вызовы `window.location.assign` происходят раз в несколько секунд - нужно действительно поискать проблему. Если же они происходят практически мгновенно подряд - срабатывает просто последний. Попробуйте теста ради в консоли браузера в цикле до 10 выполнить `location='blabla#i'` - каждый следующий прерывает предыдущий и в итоге остается работать только последний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть - проблема в слишком частом изменении `location`. Когда несколько раз подряд за короткий промежуток времени адрес страницы меняется - каждое следующие изменение отменяет предыдущее. В итоге срабатывает только последнее.

В моих опытах я реализовал скачивание трех файлов в цикле. После запуска цикла скачивается только последний файл. Браузер даже не успевает послать запрос по адресу, а адрес уже снова меняется и нужно отправлять запрос на новый.

Хорошо показал себя простейший выход: ставим запросы за файлами (в вашем случае) в таймаут с увеличивающимся интервалом. В моем случае 500мс отлично сработало:

```
var counter = 1;
$.get("", { name: name, img: img, price: price, url: url })
    .done(function(data) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.assign("/slave/instagram/parse/?name=" +name + "&img=" + img + "&price=" + price + "&url=" + url + "&category_id=" + category_id);
            console.log("Next");
        }, 500 * counter++);
    });
```

Разумеется, предполагается, что по указанному адресу скачивается файл, а страница не обновляется и продолжает работать.

Если не поможет - добавьте в вопрос больше кода, интересен цикл, в котором все это происходит.